# Close the main window and open a new one - PyQt

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

In PyQt, is it any way to close the main window and open a new one?

In particular, I am trying to close a window and open the same window all over again. I've tried every way I could think of without success (with some resulting in segmentation fault). I need to do this because the new window will have some features according to the parameters that are passed.

Comment: Post your current code. It'll make things easier to debug.

Comment: @Blender Well, after a long time trying but coincidentally soon after posting, I got it working... May I ask, should I delete the question?

Comment: You should be able to answer your own question. It'd be useful to others.

Answer (score 9):

How about this:

```
....
....

def selectMode( self ):
    self.close()
    self.field_params = params

    self.show()
```

Answer (score -3):

Well, somehow soon after posting I managed to make it work. Here is the code:

```
class GameWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):

def __init__(self, field_params):
    super(GameWindow, self).__init__()
    self.field_params = field_params

    #some code that ends up calling selectMode

    def selectMode(self):
        self.close()
        self.__init__(params)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    game_window = GameWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This is an old post but it is useful as I am in the same situation. How could I call `selectMode()` I tried `self.selectMode()` but it says the class has no selectMode.

Comment: The code is poorly formatted and provides incomplete information at best.